# Deleting comments from a post: NoReverseMatch while trying to delete comment of a post

Tags: python, html, django, django-class-based-views

I am quite new to django and web development and trying to delete the comment from posts, and has provided a class based view, but I am getting this error while running the code.

```
Reverse for 'delete_comment' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/(?P<comment_id>[0-9]+)/delete/$']
```

I have provided the comment section below and you can find the delete section towards the last.

comment-section.html

```
            {{ comments.count }} Comment{{ comments|pluralize }}
        {% for comment in comments %}
        <blockquote class="blockquote">
        <img style="float:left; clear: left;" class="rounded-circle article-img" height="50" width="50" src="{{ comment.user.profile.profile_pic.url }}"><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><h6>{{ comment.user.first_name|capfirst }} {{ comment.user.last_name|capfirst }}</h6></a><br>
        <p style="font-size: 8px;">{{ comment.timestamp }}</p>
        <p style="font-size: 14px;" class="mb-3">{{ comment.content }}</p>
        <a  type="button" name="button" class="reply-btn ml-4"><p style="font-size: 13px;"> Reply</p></a>
        {% if request.user == comment.user %}
        <a href="{% url 'posts:delete_comment' comment.id %}" style="font-size: 13px;text-decoration: none; color: #000;" hover="background-color:red">Delete</a></td>
        {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
class DeleteCommentView(BSModalDeleteView, LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'posts/comment_delete.html'
    success_message = 'Deleted'

    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse_lazy('posts:detail_post')

    def test_func(self, comment_id):
       comment = self.get_object(self.comment_id)
       if self.request.user == comment.user:
         return True
       return False
```

urls.py

```
    path('<slug>/<int:comment_id>/delete/', DeleteCommentView.as_view(), name='delete_comment'),
```

Please do let me know how can I let users delete their comments from the post. It was easier to delete the whole post.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your URL takes two arguments, `slug` and `comment_id`, but you are only passing in `comment_id` when you use the `{% url %}` tag.

It's not altogether obvious what the slug is since you don't show the model, but assuming it's the post slug, you could perhaps fix this with:

```
{% url 'posts:delete_comment' comment.post.slug comment.id %}
```

Probably the better solution however is to have your URL not take the slug at all since the ID is enough to identify it. We can't see the code for `BSModalDeleteView` but I'm guessing it is only expecting an ID, in which case you might need a new URL just for deleting comments such as:

```py
path(
   "/comments/<int:pk>/delete/",
   DeleteCommentView.as_view(),
   name="delete_comment",
)
```

Comment: Still I am getting the noreverse match error.
The slug is for the post so I was trying to fetch the slug first then the comment id, but it isn't working. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried removing the slug from the URL (second option)?

Comment: Yes I did it exactly as you mentioned.

Comment: Can you show the new error? It will be different from the first if the path has been changed.

Comment: Sure. This is the error its showing now. Is there any problem with the view fn in the class?
NoReverseMatch at /posts/jerrypaulsam-titanic/
Reverse for 'delete_comment' with arguments '('jerrypaulsam-titanic', 83)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/comments/(?P<comment_id>[0-9]+)/delete/$']

Comment: You're now passing in the slug and the ID. You should now only pass in the ID as the path doesn't accept it. You should try _one_ of the solutions I gave, not both.

Comment: Ok. but now there is an attribute error.
AttributeError at /posts/comments/83/delete/
Generic detail view DeleteCommentView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Comment: The base view, that you didn't show, appears to only accept it named a couple of ways. I've edited the answer. The argument in your path should be called `pk` or `id` as the error states.

Comment: But still it doesn't work. Now the error is: Reverse for 'detail_post' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']
I will update the view with my details view.

Comment: This is a completely unrelated error. This is talking about `detail_post`, probably from your `get_success_url()` method. I would guess the comment is being deleted, but you aren't being redirected because you aren't telling it _which_ post to redirect to. You shouldn't use `reverse_lazy()` here (since it's in a method there's nothing alzy about it), you shoud use `reverse()` and pass in the post slug. How else would it know which post to redirect to?

Comment: Ok. I will check that out!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it's working.